# Scientific studies, related to vegans and veganism

Tags: scientific-studies

Does anyone here have a compilation of good quality studies related to vegans and veganism? Would be very appreciated. Or If you have a few, you can still post, maybe we'll be able to gather them under this question. Thanks!

Comment: What are you looking for in particular? Motivations? Health effects? Impact on the climate? Policy advice? Impact on athletic performance? Etc. Etc.?

Comment: @henning interested in everything, but mostly health and athletic performance, as those are the most common arguments I face.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching "vegan", "vegetarian" and "plant-based" on Google Scholar shows over [a million results](https://scholar.google.com.br/scholar?as_q=&as_oq=vegan%20vegetarian%20plant-based).

You can find many studies related to Whole-Food Plant-Based diets presented in a more accessible manner in Dr. Michael Greger's excellent [Nutrition Facts](https://nutritionfacts.org/) website. All videos have a "Sources Cited" tab with links to all the references.

For veganism in general, not just health and diet, I don't know any good source, but on YouTube there's [Mic the Vegan](https://www.youtube.com/c/MictheVegan), who is always talking about new studies, documentaries, and news articles related to veganism. He usually gives very accurate and accessible summaries even though he's not a doctor or scientist.